# dynamically create a new wiki page in sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

i m new to sharepoint, 
i m doing a site in sharepoint 2010,

i created a list of employee details, it contains various columns, once a new item is added to that list on "ok" by a user it should redirect to a pop up button, 
and onclick of which it will directly allow a user to open a new wiki page for his own use.

and if an existing record is edited, it should open the existing wiki page for that particular user.

i have installed visual studio 2010 so  that i can create this custom webpart,

but i m new to sharepoint so i do not know where and how to start from.

could anyone please guide me through this.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create Wiki pages using programmtically in [ItemAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded%28v=office.12%29.aspx) Event receiver based on 
`add item` in list.

In ItemAdded Event You just check it out that User has wiki pages or not if not exist than create `wiki pages` programmatically.

have a look this artical :

- http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-creating-wiki-pages/
- http://sharepointx-men.com/2010/07/09/sharepoint-2010-event-receivers-part-1-create-event-receiver-for-content-types/

Hops this Helps.

Comment: i m thinking of doing the event reciever in VB instead of c#.

can you please guide me thro this?

i read the two links above,

did not quite understand ,

what is to be done actually.

:(

Comment: see this link : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/SharePoint-2010-Developing-3e946d64. Hops getting some idea to create event receiver and after on `ItemAdded` method utilize Wikipage code.